# Threads blocking during ReteMemory initialization

Tags: java, multithreading, drools, blocking

In my application, all threads are blocking during initialization of drools session

```
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
at org.drools.reteoo.common.ReteWorkingMemory.initInitialFact(ReteWorkingMemory.java:108)
    - waiting to lock <5385ba43> (a java.lang.Integer) owned by "Thead-23" t@42
    at org.drools.reteoo.common.ReteWorkingMemory.fireAllRules(ReteWorkingMemory.java:129)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1260)
    at org.drools.impl.adapters.StatefulKnowledgeSessionAdapter.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionAdapter.java:72)


java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
at org.drools.reteoo.common.ReteWorkingMemory.initInitialFact(ReteWorkingMemory.java:108)
    - waiting to lock <5385ba43> (a java.lang.Integer) owned by "Thead-01" t@42
    at org.drools.reteoo.common.ReteWorkingMemory.fireAllRules(ReteWorkingMemory.java:129)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1260)
    at org.drools.impl.adapters.StatefulKnowledgeSessionAdapter.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionAdapter.java:72)
```

The easiest way to replicate the issue is by creating a drools file with the following condition:-

> ```
> rule "slowWhenCondition" 
>   when
>       eval(mySlowCondition(fact))
>   then
>
> end
> ```

Create a StatefulSession and fire all the rules from multiple threads. Observe the threads in Blocking state using JVisualVM or Stack Trace.

Upon investigating further I figured that the following code which is invoked during the initialization of ReteWorkingMemory is causing the problem

```
private final Integer syncLock = 42;
public void initInitialFact() {
    if ( initialFactHandle == null ) {
        synchronized ( syncLock ) {
            if ( initialFactHandle == null ) {
                // double check, inside of sync point incase some other thread beat us to it.
                initInitialFact(kBase, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An Integer constant used for locking causes all threads having unrelated rules to block on each other. The most obvious fix is changing the syncLock from Integer constant to Object syncLock = new Object(). Is there any reason why it should not be changed.

I am working on Drools 6.3 Final and using Java 8 on CentOS. Each thread in the application creates its own Stateful Session.

Comment: The following issue has been raised with the suggested fix: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-1046

Comment: Neither there nor here is enough code to reproduce the issue. You'll have to add the code (as simple as possible) creating the Rule Base, the session and run it in n threads. Without, nobody will feel very excited about looking into your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by the suggested fix and is now a part of Drools 6.4. More information can be found at the following location https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-1046